# Python - faster way to do for loops

Tags: python, performance, for-loop

I was just wondering if anyone knew a faster / more efficient way to test this.

(It's suppose to write out every solution to the equation)

```
        for z in range(500):
           for x in range(500):
             for y in range(500):
               if (x * 80) + (z * 65) + (y * 50) == 1950:
                 print("x " + str(x) + " z " + str(z) + " y " + str(y))
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried list comprehensions, generators and stuff. If not please have a look at that concept. That can help you speed up the process

Comment: You mean integral solutions right? You can calculate `y` once you have `z` and `x`. You don't need the inner most for-loop.

Comment: It accepts an infinity of solutions. Are `x,y,z` positive integers?

Comment: @EricDuminil There aren't infinite solutions because it only uses integers from `range`. I'm trying to think how to use that to reduce it down. A huge part of the search space is invalid.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We assume that `x,y,z` must be positive integers. There's an infinity of solutions otherwise.

## Calculate y from x and z

Here's a method which should be 500x faster than yours, simply because it doesn't iterate over y :

```
for z in range(500):
    for x in range(500):
        fifty_y = 1950 - (x * 80) - (z * 65)
        if fifty_y >= 0 and (fifty_y % 50) == 0:
            y = fifty_y // 50
            print("x " + str(x) + " z " + str(z) + " y " + str(y))
```

By iterating over `x`, `y` and `z`, you're basically shooting in the dark and hoping that it lands on `1950`.

But you know that `50 * y = 1950 -  x * 80 - z * 65`, so you can calculate `y` directly from `x` and `z`.

`50 * y` should be positive, and if `y` is to be an integer, it should be divisible by 50.

## Restrict x and z

`range(500)` is far too big for `x` and `z` if we want `y` to be positive.

`range(1950 // 65 + 1)` should be enough for `z`.

Knowing `z`, `range((1950 - 65 * z)// 80 + 1)` will be enough for `x`.

As a bonus, we're sure that `50 * y` is positive and we can remove one test :

```
for z in range(1950 // 65 + 1):
    for x in range((1950 - 65 * z) // 80 + 1):
        fifty_y = 1950 - (x * 80) - (z * 65)
        if (fifty_y % 50) == 0:
            y = fifty_y // 50
            print("x " + str(x) + " z " + str(z) + " y " + str(y))
```

## With Wolfram Alpha

By typing the equation in [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%20*%2080)%20%2B%20(z%20*%2065)%20%2B%20(y%20*%2050)%20%3D%3D%201950), we get :

> Integer solution: y = 13 n + x, z = -10 n - 2 x + 30, n element Z

That's perfect! For any `x`, we just need to choose `n` so that both `y` and `z` are positive. There's no need for `if` anymore. This code iterates 42 times to display 42 solutions :

```
for x in range(1950 // 80 + 1):
    for n in range(- (x // 13), (30 - 2 * x) // 10 + 1):
        z = -10 * n - 2 * x + 30
        y = 13 * n + x
        print("x " + str(x) + " z " + str(z) + " y " + str(y))
```

It almost fits in one line :

```
print [(x, 13 * n + x, 30 - 10 * n - 2 * x) for x in range(25) for n in range(-(x // 13), (30 - 2 * x) // 10 + 1)]
```

This code is alsost 3 million times faster than your original code :)

Comment: Yeah, this really cuts down the time. Great solution!

Comment: @Aplex : I'm not done. Don't accept the answer so fast, there might be other interesting contributions.

Comment: @roganjosh: It finds the exact same solutions as OP's code. As I said above, there are an infinity of solutions if you accept negative integers.

Comment: @EricDuminil: great answer, small nitpick: use `//` instead of `/` (integer division)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Thanks. The python3 police is back! You're right, but I also find the `//` syntax way too heavy. It cuts the expression and looks like a Java comment.

Answer (score 3):

This will make you a generator of list containing your x,y,z values that produce 1950. The advantage of the generator construct is that the values are generated when called for instead of then the object is created.

```
the_vals = ([x,y,z] for x in range(500) for y in range(500) for z in range(500) if (x * 80) + (z * 65) + (y * 50) == 1950)
```

Then to print it out you can just do

```
for x,y,z in the_vals:
    print("x " + str(x) + " z " + str(z) + " y " + str(y))
```

Comment: you mean `(x * 80) + (z * 65) + (y * 50) == 1950` of course.

Comment: @Kyrubas You can change the list comprehension to a dictionary, which can increase the speed. the_vals = ([x,y,z] for x in range(500) for y in range(500) for z in range(500) if (x * 80) + (z * 65) + (y * 50) == 1950)

Comment: not dictionary, generator comprehension. And BTW you could avoid multiplcations using steps and dividing when found: `([x//80,y//65,z//50] for x in range(0,500*80,80) for y in range(0,500*65,65) for z in range(0,500*50,50) if x+y+z == 1950)`